# How to keep the fetching queue in order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have two more fetching requests in one page, how to arrange them one by one?

Just a code for instance, expecting the fetching queue is executed in num order.

```
class FetchingQueue extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidUpdate(preProps) {
    if ( this.props.prop1 != preProps.props1) {
      this.props.fetching1
      this.props.fetching2
      this.timeoutHanlde = setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.fetching3
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
export default connect(
  state => ({
    prop1: state.reducer.props1
  }),
  { fetching1, fetching2, fetching3 }
)(FetchingQueue)
```

Comment: Do you want those fetch calls to be called randomly or one after another?

Comment: If this fetching functions return promises you can chains them with `.then()` method: `this.props.fetching1().then(() => this.props.fetching2()).then(() => this.props.fetching3())`.

Comment: How to share the promise get from previous fetching, like `this.props.fetching1().then((propsFromFetching1Promise) => this.props.fetching2(propsFromFetching1Promis))`

Comment: Yes, I want to call them one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Just return Promises from the fetching functions and then wait for them:

```
class FetchingQueue extends Component {
  ...
  async componentDidMount() {
    const fetching1Result = await this.props.fetching1();
    const fetching2Result = await this.props.fetching2();
    const fetching3Result = await this.props.fetching3();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({ prop1: state.reducer.props1 }),
  { fetching1, fetching2, fetching3 }
)(FetchingQueue)
```

Fetching function can look like this:

```
const fetching1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // call resolve when ready
  resolve('result');
});
```